# Cannot find Redux Store in Redux Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I'm trying to debug this chat application but I can't open the Redux Dev Tools. I just get a message in the redux console saying "No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions"

The app is **not** using Redux Toolkit.

Whats wrong with this store?

/store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import loggerMiddleware from "redux-logger";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import user from "./user";
import conversations from "./conversations";
import activeConversation from "./activeConversation";

const CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT = "CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT";

export const clearOnLogout = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT,
  };
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  user,
  conversations,
  activeConversation,
});
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT) {
    // set state to initial state
    state = undefined;
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware)
);

console.log(store.getState());

export default store;
```

This is the error logged in the console

```
action SET_MESSAGE @ 10:32:54.246 redux-logger.js:1
 prev state 
Object { user: {…}, conversations: (2) […], activeConversation: "hualing" }
redux-logger.js:1
 action     
Object { type: "SET_MESSAGE", payload: {…} }
redux-logger.js:1
 error      TypeError: message is undefined
    addMessageToStore reducerFunctions.js:15
    addMessageToStore reducerFunctions.js:14
    reducer conversations.js:77
    combination Redux
    rootReducer index.js:27
    Redux 4
    postMessage thunkCreators.js:103
    middleware Redux
    postMessage Input.js:61
    handleSubmit Input.js:38
    React 14
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 15
    js index.js:7
    js main.chunk.js:4097
    Webpack 7
redux-logger.js:1
 next state 
Object { user: {…}, conversations: (2) […], activeConversation: "hualing" }
```